# Display message from properties file in Grails

Tags: grails

I am very new to Grails and during my work I am stuck in one place. For the below mention submit button I would like to fetch the value from properties file. This is done with g:message when I am displaying value under td tag but for button what will e the syntax.

```
<g:submitToRemote class="submit"  value="<g:message code='Save' default='Save' />"/>
```

Comment: It's also `<g:message.../>`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write your GSP as

```
<g:submitToRemote class="submit"  value="${g.message(code:'Save', default:'Save')}"/>
```

Comment: You can omit `g.` since it's the default namespace; it's only required when using a custom namespace.

Comment: It is true. But it is always advisable to put it, in case there is some variable name set in the request object with the same name (`message`).

Comment: One more thing if I like to use it in Jquery to change value of the button how I will use. The below code I tried but instead of display the value it's showing properties key itself.

 $("#comment").prop('value', "<g:message code='button.save' />"); 
or
if ($(this).attr("value") == "Save")

Comment: You must be carefull with the javascript code regarding to evaluation like this: ($(this).attr("value") == "Save"). It works, true, but if the language is different to English you will obtain other value. For example: "Guardar" and "Save" != "Guardar" and the condition will never be fulfilled

Comment: But how to put it in  $("#comment").prop('value', "<g:message code='button.save' />")

Comment: Step 1: Add a input[type="hidden"] like this <input type="hidden" value="${g.message(code:'Save')}" id="h"/>.  
Step 2:  $("#comment").attr('value', $('#h').val())   
Finnaly, you will have on #comment value the i18n for "Save"